# CSS full width list element

Tags: css, flexbox

I am creating a menu and am trying to have full width menu, just using CSS. However, I am not sure how menu items will be in menu.

This is a screenshot of the problem:
[image]

The problem is in the "GAP", that I get.

If I have fixed number of items, I know I could use this logic:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
li {
    padding: 10px 60px;
}
```

Is there a way to make this with using just CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: why not you create a jsfiddle to help you better?

Comment: How are you making the menu? Using horizontal lists? Is there any sample code you could provide?

Comment: tried `width: 100%`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, using flexbox.

Keep the code for the ul and simply add `flex-grow: 1` to the list.

```
li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

To make sure there is no gap between the edge of the document and the menu items, add padding: 0 to the ul element.

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/komy44x1/1/

Answer (score 1):

You're almost their, add `flex-grow:` to the li element.

```css
ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 10px 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>menu item #1</li>
 <li>menu item #2</li>
 <li>menu item #3</li>
 <li>menu item #4</li>
 <li>menu item #5</li>
 <li>menu item #6</li>
</ul>
```

Read more on flex here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/